# basic socket.io communication

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have the following setup using node.js and socket.io

server.js:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8000);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
  });
});
```

index.html:

```
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1>
<script src="http://ip:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js">
<script>

var socket = io.connect('http://ip:8000');
socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
</script>
</body></html>
```

Could anyone please tell me why I don't see any debug messages or I do not receive any communication between them?

Comment: are you able to get `http://ip:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js` inside your browser?

Comment: yes I am able to get it :)

Comment: your server console should at least print something like `debug - served static content /socket.io.js` if not, make sure you got debug mode activated (`io.set('log level', 3);`) or provide more information.

Comment: Yes it prints this -- debug - served static content /socket.io.js

Comment: But I don't see the logged data :(

Comment: Alright, but nothing else? I ask because you wrote `I don't see any debug messages`. You should see information about heartbeats and stuff. But in your example, you didn't actually listen to a socket which will recieve data, so don't expect there to be anything special ;)

Comment: No heartbeats but I shoudl see the console.log when the html is invoked right? Nothing actually happens

Comment: Add `.configure(function () {
 this.set("log level", 2);
});` after your `.listen(8000)`

Comment: You should see `info  - handshake authorized` in your console when you let the web page connect.

Comment: @StijnMartens I do not see that in the logs

Comment: Do you see any JavaScript errors in your browsers console?

Comment: @StijnMartens no errors at all

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34022/discussion-between-stijn-martens-and-pavan-k)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close your script tag:

```
<script src="http://ip:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js">
```

Add `</script`:

```
<script src="http://ip:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```